# Default value with ng-options after filter

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<select>` box with options driven from a filter, based on the value of another field in the model (another `<select>` field). If, after filtering the list, there's only one option to display, I want to make it the selected option. [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) seems like a starting point, but it's also recommended by the Angular team as something to not use.

**SELECT**:

```
 <select
    tabindex="5"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="vm.transaction.um"
    ng-options="um.name for um in vm.ums | measuresForItem:vm.transaction.item">
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to change some model value (`vm.transaction.um`) based on some other model value (filtered `vm.ums`). There is `$watch()` function that does exactly this thing. Try

```
$scope.$watch('(vm.ums | measuresForItem:vm.transaction.item).length', function(newVal) {
    if (newVal == 1)
        $scope.vm.transaction.um = (<get filtered result here>)[0].name;
});
```

Actually `ng-init` is not that bad for such sort of tasks, but it executes only once, and it might be not suitable for dynamic filters or any kind of deferring.

Comment: Where would this watch be created; in the controller?

Comment: Anywhere you have access to the $scope. Controller will do

Comment: Just realized, that it won't work. The "|" filter syntax is purely angular feature, not javascript and it will break the code when used in function body. There should be explicit invocation of measuresForItem filter (same thing that angular performs behind the scene, but done manually)

Answer (score 0):

Just set `vm.transaction.um` (the member you assigned to ng-model) in your controller:

```
if(this.vm.ums.length === 1) {
    this.vm.transaction.um = this.vm.ums[0];
}
```